# Incoming Notifications

Tags: windows-10, skype

Can an external program recognize when Skype receives an incoming call; voice, video, or message?

I see that later versions of Skype (ver 8 +) no longer support the Skype API.

When I receive a call on my Windows 10 PC a window pops up, and I assume a ring tone plays, announcing that I have a call and I can choose to answer or ignore.

Upon an incoming call I would like an external program to recognize there is a call and flash a Wi-Fi bulb.

Flashing the bulb is no problem, but I can't figure out how to recognize that Skype has an incoming call.

Skype uses the term "Notification". I don't see anything in the new notifications window in Windows 10.

How would an external program recognize on a Windows 10 PC that Skype as an incoming call?

Thanks,
Barry.